# Distributivity of direct sum over maximal tensor product

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be $C^{*}$-algebras.Does the following identity always holds:

> $(A \oplus B) \otimes^{max} C \cong (A \otimes^{max}C) \oplus (B \otimes^{max} C)$

My intuition is that this should hold but i cannot see the proof of this. Any reference/ideas?